# Query with distinct values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "sites" with a field "url"
all urls have a "id=" like:

```
http://www.google.com/&id=1234
```

I need to list all the urls that have an unique id

with this query I can list correctly but I can't really use the url

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -1), '&', 1)) FROM sites
```

maybe with regex will be better

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT url, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -1), '&', 1) FROM sites group by url
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked for me that way: SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'id=', -1), '&', 1) AS url2, url FROM sites GROUP BY url2